# Twilio returning a 500 internal server error when trying to obtain response from my web snippet

Tags: twilio

Ahoy!

I installed Twilio in Laravel and ran the code below at the routes (though also I reproduced it at the Controller using this same code in a function)

Now I dont have any issue with namespaces or trying to access the class as it gives no error when using the method against it.

The snippet is as simple as this:

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/incoming', function()
{
  $twiml = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
  $twiml->say('Hello - your app just answered the phone. Neat, eh?', array('voice' => 'alice'));
  $response = Response::make($twiml, 200);
  $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  return $response;
});
```

So I got my phonenumber and went to the Twilio page and added to the URL to which the phone is bound the URL where this snippet is located

sort of www.maweb.con/incoming

I then ring the phone from the kitchen (this shouldn't make a difference lol) and then I get an email error from Twilion saying that when "they" went to that URL to retrieve information and that all they got was an Internal Server error 500.

I stuck my nose into the details of the error and I found this:

```
<abbr title="Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException">TokenMismatchException</abbr> in
```

I am familiar with that kind of errors, that happens also when you are trying to send a parameter via an Ajax snippet. You need to make an exception at the VerifyToken php file in the Middleware, but I cannot know what the parameter is now, since it must be using the Twiml library and god knows what's in there, it is a blackbox.

I haven't Required the twilio. I just installed it via composer, but like I said, it does recognize the class services_twilio_twlim now. The error is when trying to obtain a response when accessing to that URL.

For a Web not based on a framework I have included:

```
<?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
require_once('twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php');

?>
<Response>
    <Say>Hello Monkey</Say>
</Response>
```

Comment: Can you access that URL yourself? If not, I think that's the first thing to look at. If you can't see it, chances are Twilio won't be able to see it either. I;m no PHP developer, but don't you need something like `require "/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php";` at the top of your page?

Comment: hi, about the "require" I think that is when you are not using frameworks, when you are on plain php and you have not installed it through composer. That would the case when you upload a zip file and place it in some directory, Then you would need to require it. Otherwise, I include the namespace to the twilio class like: use Services_Twilio_Twiml. If the class were not found, that would be the first thing it would complain about. I can access the URL myself.

Comment: Ok,  if you can access it yourself when it's in that environment I would guess it's because your page is not available externally. So Twilio can't see it.

Comment: Can you give me the URL to your website (where you're hosting the XML)? It looks as though the problem id with twilio being able to see your website as opposed to this being a Twilio problem (you just proved it by pointing your number to a different URL and it worked)

Comment: Then it sounds like you haven't configured your number to make a request to that URL

Comment: Solved. It has worked at http://techtranslators.eu/hello-monkey.php   However I have to look into it regarding the other web which uses Framework and Namespace, but that is definitively not a Twilio issue but how to invoke it the class from Laravel in a way that works.

Comment: Marcos, read my posted answer, you should include it as an Issue on your documentation but how can be solved is here in this answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read and talk to our developer education team. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.1  From 5.0 a protection against cross site scripting was introduced and all ajax request that you use like the one for example for interdependent select lists are blocked by a MiddleWare in Laravel. In order to unblock that particular snippet you need to include the route the ajax is posting to in a file called verfycssr.php. We can do that when we write the ajax code ourselves, but if the code is in an external library we can't deal with it. Using http get is the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is something that I hope will help others when working with Twilio applications:

First of all Twilio is fantastic and I love it but one needs to know how to, of course, as with everything:

You need to know the critical importance between the coding scenarios: you may be working with a PHP framework or you may be coding native PHP and not using any MVC

- If you are using Laravel, you will need to import the class by:

  use Services_Twilio_Twiml;

and I assumme you have installed the Twilio class through Composer.

if you are not on a Framework just do the old require_once(path to your Twilio.php file) something like Twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php

Now, the issue that had me stuck for a while.

Even if you correctly enter the URL at your Twilio page and your telephone is correctly configured to point at it, if you are using Laravel, as Twilio sends its data through POST (by default) the Token Protection against XSS in Laravel will block it by means of the VerifyCSSR Middleware file.
Since you cannot see what values is Posting, you cannot add them to the exceptions and your application will never work.
Therefore, you need to send it via the URL query, that is, change it to HTTP GET.